# What is a simple workflow to use docker in Windows with a basic file sharing possibility?

Tags: windows, docker

For the sake of simplicity, use `ubuntu` image as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often find it easier to use docker-compose, particularly if there's a high chance I'll want to both mount-volumes *and* link the container to another container at some point in the future.

1. Create a folder for working in, say "ubuntu".
2. In the "ubuntu" folder, create another folder called "files"
3. Create a file in that folder called "docker-compose.yml". In this file, enter:

   ```
   ubuntucontainer:
       image: "ubuntu:latest"
       ports: 
           - "80:80"
       volumes:
           - ./files:/files
   ```
4. Whenever you need to start the box, navigate to "ubuntu" and type `docker-compose up`. To stop again, use `docker-compose stop`.

The advantage of using docker compose is that if you ever want to link-up a database container this can be done easily by adding another container to the yaml file, and then in the ubuntucontainer container adding a `links` section.

Not to mention, `docker-compose up` is quite minimal on the typing.

(Also, forwarding the ports with `80:80` may not be strictly necessary, it depends on what you want the box to do.)

Comment: Docker-compose seems very convenient if I could make it work. I get this error : Creating files_ubuntucontainer_1
Attaching to files_ubuntucontainer_1
`[36mfiles_ubuntucontainer_1 exited with code 0
[0m

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR version:

1. Open **Docker Quickstart Terminal**. If it is already open, run `$ cd ~`
2. Run this **once**: `$ docker run -it -v /$(pwd)/ubuntu:/windows --name ubu ubuntu`
3. To start every time: `$ docker start -i ubu`

You will get an empty folder named `ubuntu` in your Windows user directory. You will see this folder with the name `windows` in your ubuntu container.

#### Explanation:

1. `cd ~` is for making sure you are in Windows user directory.
2. `-it` stands for interactive, so you can interact with the container in the terminal environment. `-v host_folder:container_folder` enables sharing a folder between the host and the container. The host folder should be inside the Windows user folder. `/$(pwd)` translates to `//c/Users/YOUR_USER_DIR` in Windows 10. `--name ubu` assigns the name `ubu` to the container.
3. `-i` stands for interactive